# Proof for nth term of the sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

""If $t_1,t_2,t_3,.......$ is a sequence such that the first differences are in G.P with common ratio r, then its nth term is $t_n= ar^n + b$. ""

Is this statement correct. How can we prove this statement?
I didn't get any idea to prove this. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Let $s_n = t_{n+1}-t_n$. Then it can be shown by induction that $s_n = (t_2-t_1)r^{n-1}$. We therefore have that 
$$t_{n+1} = (t_2-t_1)r^{n-1}+t_n := cr^n+t_n$$
We then see that, for instance, $t_5 = cr^4+cr^3+cr^2+cr+t_1$. More generally, it can be shown by induction that
$$t_{n+1} = t_1+c\sum_{k=1}^nr^n = t_1+c\frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}-c$$
After some rearrangement, you can get this into the desired form.